# How to data import without tag from database using draft-js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

i'm making simple editor with draft-js  
If save the data to the database and import it again, the tag appears....

take a look pic

[image]

Comment: If you need just the plain text without any RTF, use `getCurrentContent().getPlainText()` method of the `editorState`

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the editor content with html string. Draft.js provides api to do that.

```
const sampleMarkup =
  '<b>Bold text</b>, <i>Italic text</i><br/ ><br />' +
  '<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Example link</a>';
const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup);
const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
  blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
  blocksFromHTML.entityMap,
);
this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(state),
};
```

[convertFromHTML reference](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion/#convertfromhtml)